# Ruby AdWords API retornando AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_INVALID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth2

Estou usando:

- devise
- omniauth
- omniauth-google-oauth2
- google-adwords-api

e pego o token pelo callback do oauth:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    session[:token] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials
    ...
  end
end
```

estou seguindo o exemplo do [adwords on rails](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/master/adwords_api/examples/adwords_on_rails) para instanciar a API

```
 def adwords_api
   @api ||= create_adwords_api
 end

 def create_adwords_api
   api = AdwordsApi::Api.new Rails.application.config_for(:adwords)

   token = session[:token]
   if token
     credentials = api.credential_handler
     credentials.set_credential :oauth2_token, token
     credentials.set_credential :client_customer_id, current_user.id
   end
   api
 end
```

Mas quando tento buscar as campanhas aparece esse erro:
`[AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_INVALID @ ; trigger:'<null>'`

e baseado no log, essa é a url da request:
`[2015-01-09T10:12:44.237172 #6481] DEBUG -- : SOAP request: https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201409/CampaignService`

o que faz ocorrer esse erro? e como arrumar?